# Vb.Net 256 Hash to PHP 256 Hash

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, hash

I have VB.Net method that does this:

```vb
' Step 1: UTF8 Encodes
Dim uEncode As New UnicodeEncoding()

' Step 2: Creates Byte Array from UTF8 encoded string
Dim bytClearString() As Byte = uEncode.GetBytes(ClearString)

' Step 3: Creates the hash from the byte array
Dim sha As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed()
Dim hash() As Byte = sha.ComputeHash(bytClearString)

' Base64 Encodes the hash
Return Convert.ToBase64String(hash)
```

In PHP I'm doing this:

```php
// Step 1 utf8 encode
$tohash = utf8_encode('testinfostring');

// Step 2 cast string to byte array
Not sure about this step...

// Step 3
$hash = hash('sha256', $tohash, true);

// Step 4 convert hashed array to base64 encoded string
echo base64_encode($hash);
```

The output from my VB.Net method differs from the PHP and I think it's that VB encryption is happening on the byte array while PHP is on the string itself.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide code, rather than pseudo code so folks can see what is actually happening.

Comment: For starters, in VB.NET you should use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClearString)` instead.

Comment: Which do you prefer to happen -- hashing the raw byte array or the text value?

Comment: @Theo that's not pseudo code...

Comment: @VisualVincent - Good point but I should have stated that the VB code is legacy and the data it has produced is already in production.  The PHP code needs to mimic the VB.Net Code

Comment: Apologies. The formatting at the time made it appear so. Thanks @Visual Vincent for reformatting.

Comment: My point was that `UnicodeEncoding` is not the same as `UTF8Encoding`. According to [**the documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) the `UnicodeEncoding` class _"Represents a **UTF-16** encoding of Unicode characters"_. This can also be confirmed by doing a test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9SiF7b - as you see the `UnicodeEncoding` class uses two bytes per character, just like UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent ,  your explanation led me to the answer.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the PHP from:

```
$tohash = utf8_encode('testinfostring');
```

to:

```
$tohash = mb_convert_encoding('testinfostring', 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Tip: To format code properly insert four (4) spaces in front of each code line.